# How to create an snapshot for MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a table in MySQL database which is updated every five seconds. I want to take a snapshots of the table for testing purposes. How can i achieve this without affecting on table updating process?

Answer (score 2):

A super-simple solution would involve `mysqldump` with `--single-transaction` option, which effectively starts a transaction and performs the dump. As this is happening within a transaction, you will get a consistent state of the database upon every dump (you can also instruct mysqldump to export only specific tables etc) and will have almost no impact on the writes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [Raw Data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/5.7/en/replication-howto-rawdata.html) Files method.

**EDIT**:

To create a raw data snapshot of MyISAM tables when your MySQL data files exist on a single file system, you can use standard file copy tools such as cp or copy, a remote copy tool such as scp or rsync, an archiving tool such as zip or tar, or a file system snapshot tool such as dump. If you are replicating only certain databases, copy only those files that relate to those tables. For InnoDB, all tables in all databases are stored in the system tablespace files, unless you have the innodb_file_per_table option enabled.

*The following files are not required for replication:*

Files relating to the mysql database.

The replica's connection metadata repository file, if used (see Section 5.4, “Relay Log and Replication Metadata Repositories”).

The source's binary log files, with the exception of the binary log index file if you are going to use this to locate the source's binary log coordinates for the replica.

Any relay log files.

Depending on whether you are using InnoDB tables or not, choose one of the following:

If you are using InnoDB tables, and also to get the most consistent results with a raw data snapshot, shut down the source server during the process, as follows:

Acquire a read lock and get the source's status. See Section 2.2.3, “Obtaining the Replication Source's Binary Log Coordinates”.

In a separate session, shut down the source server:

```
mysqladmin shutdown
```

Make a copy of the MySQL data files. The following examples show common ways to do this. You need to choose only one of them:

```
tar cf /tmp/db.tar ./data
zip -r /tmp/db.zip ./data
rsync --recursive ./data /tmp/dbdata
```

Restart the source server.

If you are not using InnoDB tables, you can get a snapshot of the system from a source without shutting down the server as described in the following steps:

Acquire a read lock and get the source's status. See Section 2.2.3, “Obtaining the Replication Source's Binary Log Coordinates”.

Make a copy of the MySQL data files. The following examples show common ways to do this. You need to choose only one of them:

```
tar cf /tmp/db.tar ./data
zip -r /tmp/db.zip ./data
rsync --recursive ./data /tmp/dbdata
```

In the client where you acquired the read lock, release the lock:

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Once you have created the archive or copy of the database, copy the files to each replica before starting the replication process.

Comment: This page does not exists anymore.